# Could C# delegate point to another class/object's method?

Tags: c#, function, class, methods, delegates

Here, I wish to gain a delegate like function pointer, to point to a class method that's in another class (named Inner), and then pass it to a static function, like below:

```
public class Inner
{
    public int M = 3;
    public void F() { Console.WriteLine("f"); }
    public void G() { Console.WriteLine("g"); }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Caller(Action a)
    {
        a();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var i = new Inner();
        var f = i.F;
        var g = i.G;
        f();//error
        g();//error
        Program.Caller(f);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I'm from c/c++, and in c/c++, function pointer like this is very straight forward, but this C# code fail to compile. I googled and found almost all delegate explanations talks about delegate that points to class method inside itself.

My question is, how to fix the code to make it work?

Comment: The answers so far will work, but for use in a larger context you might want to read up on _Dependency Injection_. `Unity` is one of the most used frameworks for this in .Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Coding Seb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60618116/8126362) highlight's the cause of the issue, but doesn't really explain why.

It is because `i.F` is a method group, and not a specific method pointer. For example, imagine `Inner` was defined as so:

```
public class Inner
{
    public void F() { Console.WriteLine("f"); }
    public void F(string name) { Console.WriteLine(name); }
}
```

Which method would `i.F` refer to? `F()` or `F(string)`?

For that reason, you need to define the variable type explicitly, or cast the pointer:

```
Action f = i.F;
```

Or:

```
var f = (Action)i.F;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not set methods group in implicit variables in C# so if you just change 2 `var` in `Action` it's working

```cs
public class Inner
{
    public int M = 3;
    public void F() { Console.WriteLine("f"); }
    public void G() { Console.WriteLine("g"); }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Caller(Action a)
    {
        a();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var i = new Inner();
        Action f = i.F;
        Action g = i.G;
        f();
        g();
        Program.Caller(f);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```